# Instagram Subscription :Challenge verification failed

Tags: curl, instagram

Does `Instagram` Allow to use `Subdoamin` for `Callback Url` ?

Can some one let me guide what could be the possible reasons for

```
: {
meta: {
error_type: "APISubscriptionError",
code: 400,
error_message: "Challenge verification failed. Sent "549830bffdaf4617a20639318a618e27", received " 549830bffdaf4617a20639318a618e27"."
}
}
```

Although i have specified All information accurately (except this `Subdomain` Usage in `Callback` `URI`. I am using `curl`...

Answer (score 1):

You need to return $_GET["hub_challenge"] to instagram to authenticate yourself.

One main problem many faced is additional header (such such google analytics).

This is my code that works, for your reference:

```
<?php print $_GET["hub_challenge"]; exit(1);?>
```